# Windows phone 7 - Json parse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a 3rd party library to parse a json string in Windows Phone 7?
In windows phone 8 I use JSON.Net (Newtonsoft), but when I tried to install it in my WP7.1 project, it gives me an error.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install older version of Newtonsoft Libs. 
version 4. should work, as I have same in my wp7.1 project.

using nuget.

```
PM > Get-Package -Filter Newtonsoft -ListAvailable -AllVersions
```